# React Native with EAS: lateinit property descriptionAdapter has not been initalized

Tags: android, react-native, eas

Every time I navigate back from a window in my stack, my app crashes with the message:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property descriptionAdapter has not been initialized
at com.doublesymmetry.kotlinaudio.notification.NotificationManager$destroy$1.invokeSuspend(NotificationManager.kt:295)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

I am confused primarily because the stack trace points to java and kotlin files (based off of Android Studio), but no where in my project am I writing these languages (the whole point of using EAS was to avoid this).

I am currently using EAS and running my code on a physical android device.

Here are my files:

The app.json file.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "my_app",
    "slug": "my_app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "io.expo.client"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "165f58a1-dbcf-4459-a5a1-53e5abbbc565"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my eas.json file.

```
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 1.1.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Lastly, here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.9",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.2.1",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~1.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-track-player": "^2.2.0-rc3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.11.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.